# Call a jQuery function and 2 JS functions on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call this jQuery function on button click. Bud I already have two functions in js .
Problem is three functions are not working. Either func1(), func2() (these are placed in external file.)  or jQuery function is executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#submit').bind("click",function()   
    {   
        var imgVal = $('#id1').val(); 
        if(imgVal=='')   
        { 
            $("#modal-body").text("Error");
            $('#Function1').trigger('click'); 

        } 
        func1();func2();
        return false;            
    }); 
});
</script> 

<input type="file" name="name1" id="id1" size="30" /> 
<input type="submit" name="name2" id="submit"  class="class1" value="upload" /> 


<button type="submit" id="submit1"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="func1();func2();" >Submit</button>

//On clicking this button three functions have to be checked
```

Comment: can you please explain clearly what exactly you want ..

Comment: *"But I have two buttons of same id's"* - well that's one problem right there. IDs must *always* be unique; no duplicates. [MDN on IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return false` has to be after the `func1()` and `func2()` calls, the `onclick="func1();func2()"` in the submit button can be removed.

Correct way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#submit').on("click",function()   
    {   
        var imgVal = $('#id1').val(); 
        if(imgVal=='')   
        { 
            $("#modal-body").text("Error");
            $('#Function1').trigger('click'); 

        } 

        func1();
        func2();
        return false; 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

I've also added a working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q9mo9c0c/1/

Comment: Checked that. Thanks!

Comment: How to make input type file as mandatory without using "required" because it gives error message there itself, but I need a pop up

Comment: Just want clarify that `bind` is deprecated as 3.0 version!